# Вернуть массив их файла, чтобы каждая строка имела свой индекс

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, массивы, веб-программирование

Делаю toDo лист. Пользователь вводит новую задачу, эта задача с новой строки записывается в файл и потом считывается весь файл, чтобы вывести весь список задач. Хранится файл на сервере.

На стороне PHP получаю массив из файла с данными и отправляю его обратно на JS. Каждая запись в файле идёт с новой строки. Нужно, чтобы каждая строка имела свой индекс, по которому к ней можно обратиться. 
В данный момент, имею такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При обращении по индексу получаю лишь символ.
PHP код:

```
 $file = file_get_contents("toDoList.txt");
        echo $file;
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что файл с данными лежит на стороне сервера, пользователь к нему никакого отношения не имеет?

Comment: Делаю toDo лист. Пользователь вводит новую задачу, эта задача с новой строки записывается в файл и потом считывается весь файл, чтобы вывести весь список задач. Хранится на сервере.

Comment: Лучше бы это указать в вопросе, чтобы пользователи понимали, о чем идет речь. Сейчас напишу решение.

Comment: А почему Вы выбрали хранить todo-лист в файле, а не в какой-либо БД?

Comment: Решил попрактиковаться. Не знаю, как его правильно нужно хранить. Первое, что пришло в голову - файл.

Comment: Для хранения данных лучше выбрать БД, нежели записывать все в файлы. Причин несколько: безопасность, реляционность данных, удобство использования...к примеру, Вы захотите сделать регистрацию и авторизацию на сервере, после чего todo-лист будет для каждого пользователя свой. В БД решается простым способом: к каждому todo-item'у добавляем значение `user_id`, теперь наш итем явно относится к какому-либо пользователю. С файлом так сделать не получится, нужно будет менять логику получения данных из файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить массив из строки, его нужно разделить. Сделать это можно с помощью функции [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). Поскольку разделителем в данном случае выступает перенос строки, то в `explode` мы передаем разделитель `\n`.

```
$file = file_get_contents("toDoList.txt");
$todos = explode('\n', $file);
```

Теперь `$todos` - это массив из строк, указанных в файле. Чтобы отдать в js уже готовый todo массив, нам нужно его перевести в json формат:

```
//переводим данные в json
$response = json_encode($todos);
//указываем, что отдаем json
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//выводим json в тело ответа
echo $response;
```

Теперь в ответе будет корректный json.

Comment: Я получаю в ответе Array и ситуация повторяется. При обращении, например, result[0] получаю букву A

Comment: попробуйте сделать `var_dump($file)`, что выведет?

Comment: Выводит string(47) и все записи из файла с новой строки

Comment: Когда я вывожу через var_dump, то выводит нормальный массив, но при попытке вывести в js получается всякая дичь

Comment: Так чтобы отдать этот массив в js, его сначала нужно привести в json. Сейчас изменю ответ.

Comment: Приводил. Не получалось. Щас снова попробую

Comment: Получается вот так(это после JSON.stringify): "[\"mnbmhg\\r\\n\",\"mnbmhgvcxvfd\\r\\n\",\"jhk\\r\\n\",\"jghj\\r\\n\",\"kjhk\\r\\n\",\"jkhk\\r\\n\",\"\\r\\n\"]"

Comment: Дополнил ответ, проверьте. Вы пытаетесь перевести данные из json в строку на стороне клиента, что в корне неверно.

Comment: Добавил dataType: "json" и заработало. Спасибо большое вам за помощь